# How create pages in my website using php without wordpress?

Tags: php, variables

I am developing a website without cms. I create my own cms without wordpress or other cms ...

I wonder, how to create pages from a form, whose link would look like this:

```
mywebsite.ext/pages/that-my-new-page/
```

I know the way to create pages with a get parameter in the url (pages.php?p=1) The pages.php page will just look for the id in my database and display the content...

In the past, I coded a script that took the code from a typical page, and added the information filled in the form and completed it in the page, then we created the "that-my-new-page" folder in inside the "pages" folder and finally, create the index.php page with the generated code inside. Like :

```
<?php
if ($pageid == NULL) { $pageid = "1"; } // verify if no page was already created

$newfolder = "pages/" . $form_submited_title_parsed . "_" . $form_submited_username . "_" . $timestamp; // my folder variables

mkdir($newfolder, 0777); //create with chmod 777
?>
<?php
//// Define page content [is a php type page, contents are generated by reading the table with the $pageid value]
$jerk = file_get_contents('jerk/typepage.txt'); // that my php type page.
$content ='<?php $pageid = "' . $pageid . '";?>' . $jerk . '';

$filename = $newfolder . "/" . "index.php"; // That is the name of the file, here index.php

$open = fopen($filename, 'w');// Took fopen in a variable for the fwrite function

fwrite($open, $content);// Write

fclose($open);// Close

// then continue, write $pageid in the db etc ...
?>
```

Finality, the link mysite.ext/pages/that-my-new-page took me directly to the page created.

**However, I would like to know if this is the only way to do it ? Thats is my question.**
Thank you all

Comment: use rewrites for `/pages/that-my-new-page/` then treat `that-my-new-page` as a page slug which identifies the page which you query against a database row, select the row and display it, you dont need to create a physical file for every page on the site, if you want to add the page on the fly, on select, if not found insert a new row

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh, that really good ! If I understand correctly, I have to parse the url to add/remove the hyphens, that is my slug/deslug function.

Afterwards, I have to configure my htaccess to send me all the unknown addresses after the "pages" folder to pages.php?p=that-my-page.
This last file, pages.php, will go to the database to find the line in question, and so if correspond show page, else go to 404 ?

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and then use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's (which you set up in your application) instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It's how most frameworks and CMS's do it. And since you only need one single rule (that redirects all requests to non-existing files to index.php), it's easier to move it between web servers (not all uses htaccess).